# What is the difference between the proxy settings in config.json and on the UI in docker?

Tags: proxy, docker

Docker seems to have two places to specify the proxy settings. One is ~/.docker/config.json, with the "proxies" key. The other can be reached via the docker desktop "Resources -> Proxies". They don't seem to be one and the same, because when I set the proxy with the latter, the information is not written in the config.json.

What is the difference between the two settings? documentation is not clear either?

Answer (score 1):

These two places have different scopes.

The proxy configured within Docker Desktop is used for every docker command. It will be mainly used for `docker pull`.

The proxy configured within `~/.docker/config.json` will be loaded in each container you start.